# issues npx create-next-app --example with-tailwindcss with-tailwindcss-app Creating a new Next.js

Tags: javascript, web, next.js, software-distribution, evernote-app-notebook

I want to create the `next.js` with `tailwindcss`, but it is not creating the project. It only creates the `README.md` file.

I used the following command to build the project:

```bash
npx create-next-app -e with-tailwindcss my-project
```

Comment: Add the error you are seeing to the question.